# Ansible logical AND with conditions not working

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I try to run task depending on two conditions using logical "and". For the first condition I created the following task:

```
- name: Check if configuration already exists, then skip next task
  stat:
    path: "{{openldap_config}}/cn=config"
  register: is_configured
```

Then I crated the following task, which is working fine:

```
 - name: add new basic-configuration
   shell: /opt/symas/sbin/slapadd -n 0 -F {{openldap_config}} -l /home/{{ansible_user}}/config.ldif
   args:
     executable: /bin/bash
   when: not is_configured.stat.exists
```

If a configuration file exists the task will be skipped. Then I have a few task where I use "group_names" like this on:

```
- name: generating deltasyncrepl LDIF for main DB
  template:
    src: main_db_repl.j2
    dest: /home/{{ansible_user}}/main-db-repl.ldif
    owner: "{{ansible_user}}"
    group: "{{ansible_group}}"
    mode: '660'
  when: "'ldap_provider' in group_names"
```

That's also working. BUT now I would like to have a logical "and" for both conditions:

```
- name: add replication of cn=config to all provider
shell: /opt/symas/bin/ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /home/{{ansible_user}}/repl_config.ldif
args:
  executable: /bin/bash
when: not is_configured.stat.exists
      and "'ldap_provider' in group_names"
```

This is not working. I tried different quoting but I could not find a a working solution. I try it with brackets too, also not working. Some how it must be possible to have a logical AND with a int- and a string- variable.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Foremost, please ban the phrase "This is not working." It's obvious that it's not working otherwise you wouldn't be asking, but what is the error or what happens instead? In this specific case, it's obvious, but that doesn't make my point less true. Anyway, you have included yaml quoting characters when they're no longer required; remove the `"` to make it `and 'ldap_provider' in group_names`.

Answer (score 1):

While you can manually stat the file and that works just fine, this is actually exactly the case that the `creates` parameter to the `shell` and `command` modules is designed to handle. You should also migrate to the `cmd` parameter (supported since Ansible 2.0) instead of using `args`, so that people reading your code don't have to understand that rarely-used syntax:

```yaml
- name: Basic configuration for OpenLDAP
  shell:
    cmd: /opt/symas/sbin/slapadd -n 0 -F {{ openldap_config }} -l /home/{{ ansible_user }}/config.ldif
    executable: /bin/bash
    creates: "{{ openldap_config }}/cn=config"
  register: openldap_config_result
```

While you didn't include your other attempts at solving this problem, generally the best way to apply multiple conditions to a task is to use a list, which will implicitly apply `and` between each condition in the list:

```yaml
- name: Add replication of cn=config to all providers
  shell:
    cmd: /opt/symas/bin/ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /home/{{ ansible_user }}/repl_config.ldif
    executable: /bin/bash
  when:
    - openldap_config_result is changed
    - "'ldap_provider' in group_names"
```

You can also do it as a single string, though you have to make sure your quoting is correct (which it isn't in your question):

```yaml
  when: openldap_config_result is changed
        and 'ldap_provider' in group_names
```

Comment: I did it with a list and it's working now. Thank you also for the better way to use the shell module, I change this too.